# Is there a way to automatically detect links in Django templates?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am passing in some lists from a view into a django template. In this template, it will extract strings from these lists in a sequence of for loops, and then print out each of these strings. Some of these strings may have URLs in them, like `This is some string. http://google.com`
Right now when these strings are printed they are just printed as text. Is there a simple way to tell the django template to autolink these URLs and show these as links instead of plain text?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try with [urlize](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#urlize) template tag.